R segfault Parallel Process with RestRserve and mcparallel
R Segmentation Fault in Parallel Process with RestRserve and mcparallel
I'm developing a REST API using RestRserve in R to manage trading bots. The API allows starting and stopping bot processes. However, I'm encountering segmentation faults and other memory-related errors when starting and stopping bots multiple times. My goal is baisically to create a REST API that can spawn and manage long running processes (bots) in parallel.
Here's a minimal example that reproduces the issue:
Minimal example
box::use(RestRserve[Application, BackendRserve])
box::use(R6)
box::use(later)
box::use(parallel)
box::use(uuid)

# Define the TradeBot class
TradeBot <- R6$R6Class(
    "TradeBot",
    public = list(
        is_running = FALSE,
        timer = NULL,
        id = NULL,
        bot_file = NULL,
        initialize = function(id, bot_file) {
            self$bot_file <- bot_file
            self$is_running <- FALSE
            self$timer <- NULL
            self$id <- id
        },
        start = function() {
            if (!self$is_running) {
                self$is_running <- TRUE
                private$run()
                cat(sprintf("Bot %s started\n", self$id))
            } else {
                cat(sprintf("Bot %s is already running\n", self$id))
            }
        },
        stop = function() {
            if (self$is_running) {
                self$is_running <- FALSE
                if (!is.null(self$timer)) {
                    self$timer()
                    self$timer <- NULL
                }
                cat(sprintf("Bot %s stopped\n", self$id))
            } else {
                cat(sprintf("Bot %s is not running\n", self$id))
            }
        }
    ),
    private = list(
        check_status = function() {
            tryCatch({
                processes <- readRDS(self$bot_file)
                if (is.null(processes[[self$id]])) {
                    self$stop()
                    return(FALSE)
                }
                return(TRUE)
            }, error = function(e) {
                cat(sprintf("Error checking status for Bot %s: %s\n", self$id, e$message))
                return(FALSE)
            })
        },
        run = function() {
            if (!private$check_status()) {
                return(NULL)
            }
            cat(sprintf("Bot %s is running\n", self$id))
            self$timer <- later$later(function() {
                tryCatch({
                    private$run()
                }, error = function(e) {
                    cat(sprintf("Error in Bot %s: %s\n", self$id, e$message))
                    self$stop()
                })
            }, 1, loop = later$global_loop())
        }
    )
)

# Use file to store bot processes; simulates database
bot_file <- "bot_processes.Rds"
if (!file.exists(bot_file)) {
    processes <- list()
    saveRDS(processes, file = bot_file)
}

# Function to start a new bot process
start_bot_process <- function(bot_id) {
    processes <- readRDS(bot_file)
    if (!is.null(processes[[bot_id]])) {
        return(FALSE) # Bot already exists
    }

    bot_process <- parallel$mcparallel({
        tryCatch({
            bot <- TradeBot$new(bot_id, bot_file)
            bot$start()
            while (bot$is_running) {
                later$run_now(all = TRUE, loop = later$global_loop())
                Sys.sleep(0.1)  # Add a small delay to prevent excessive CPU usage
            }
        }, error = function(e) {
            cat("Error in bot process:", e$message, "\n")
        }, finally = {
            cat(sprintf("Bot %s process exiting\n", bot_id))
        })
    })

    processes[[bot_id]] <- list(pid = bot_process$pid)
    saveRDS(processes, file = bot_file)
    return(TRUE)
}

# Function to stop a bot process
stop_bot_process <- function(bot_id) {
    processes <- readRDS(bot_file)
    if (is.null(processes[[bot_id]])) {
        return(FALSE) # Bot doesn't exist
    }

    # Signal the bot to stop
    processes[[bot_id]] <- NULL
    saveRDS(processes, file = bot_file)
    
    # Wait for the process to finish
    Sys.sleep(2)
    
    return(TRUE)
}

# Create the REST API application
app <- Application$new()

app$add_get("/", function(request, response) {
    response$set_body("Welcome to the Trade Bot API")
})

app$add_get("/start-bot", function(request, response) {
    bot_id <- request$parameters_query[["id"]]
    if (is.null(bot_id)) {
        bot_id <- uuid$UUIDgenerate()
    }
    if (start_bot_process(bot_id)) {
        response$set_body(sprintf("Bot %s started", bot_id))
    } else {
        response$set_status_code(400)
        response$set_body(sprintf("Bot %s already running", bot_id))
    }
})

app$add_get("/stop-bot", function(request, response) {
    bot_id <- request$parameters_query[["id"]]
    if (is.null(bot_id)) {
        response$set_status_code(400)
        response$set_body("Bot ID is required")
        return(NULL)
    }
    if (stop_bot_process(bot_id)) {
        response$set_body(sprintf("Bot %s stopped", bot_id))
    } else {
        response$set_status_code(400)
        response$set_body(sprintf("Bot %s not found or could not be stopped", bot_id))
    }
})

app$add_get("/list-bots", function(request, response) {
    processes <- readRDS(bot_file)
    bot_list <- names(processes)
    response$set_body(paste("Running bots:", paste(bot_list, collapse = ", ")))
})

# Start the server
backend <- BackendRserve$new()
backend$start(app, http_port = 8080)

Problem
When I start and stop bots multiple times using curl commands, I encounter various memory-related errors:
(base) work@Derecks-MacBook-Air dev % Rscript rest-bots-independent/index.R 
{"timestamp":"2024-08-14 21:05:32.656289","level":"INFO","name":"Application","pid":32644,"msg":"","context":{"http_port":8080,"endpoints":{"HEAD":["/","/start-bot","/stop-bot","/list-bots"],"GET":["/","/start-bot","/stop-bot","/list-bots"]}}}
-- running Rserve in this R session (pid=32644), 2 server(s) --
(This session will block until Rserve is shut down)
Bot 1a861785-533f-4cf1-b668-6986da137c23 is running
Bot 1a861785-533f-4cf1-b668-6986da137c23 started
Bot 1a861785-533f-4cf1-b668-6986da137c23 is running
Bot 1a861785-533f-4cf1-b668-6986da137c23 is running
Bot 1a861785-533f-4cf1-b668-6986da137c23 is running
Bot 1a861785-533f-4cf1-b668-6986da137c23 stopped
Bot 1a861785-533f-4cf1-b668-6986da137c23 process exiting

 *** caught bus error ***
address 0x102f47028, cause 'invalid alignment'

 *** caught  ***
Bot 158977f5-0cd6-4302-ad01-3e905f79387e is running
Bot 158977f5-0cd6-4302-ad01-3e905f79387e started
Bot 158977f5-0cd6-4302-ad01-3e905f79387e is running
Bot 158977f5-0cd6-4302-ad01-3e905f79387e is running
Bot 158977f5-0cd6-4302-ad01-3e905f79387e is running
Bot 158977f5-0cd6-4302-ad01-3e905f79387e stopped
Bot 158977f5-0cd6-4302-ad01-3e905f79387e process exiting

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x4000000102f47018, cause 'invalid permissions'
Bot 3a472bc4-8a32-4980-9120-52985ce41ce5 is running
Bot 3a472bc4-8a32-4980-9120-52985ce41ce5 started
Bot 3a472bc4-8a32-4980-9120-52985ce41ce5 is running
Bot 3a472bc4-8a32-4980-9120-52985ce41ce5 is running
Bot 3a472bc4-8a32-4980-9120-52985ce41ce5 stopped
Bot 3a472bc4-8a32-4980-9120-52985ce41ce5 process exiting

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x4000000102f47228, cause 'invalid permissions'
Bot 6259a15d-03f1-4174-8155-e5e4677811aa is running
Bot 6259a15d-03f1-4174-8155-e5e4677811aa started
Bot 6259a15d-03f1-4174-8155-e5e4677811aa is running
Bot 6259a15d-03f1-4174-8155-e5e4677811aa stopped
Bot 6259a15d-03f1-4174-8155-e5e4677811aa process exiting

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x4000000102f47228, cause 'invalid permissions'
{"timestamp":"2024-08-14 21:06:37.898974","level":"ERROR","name":"Application","pid":33791,"msg":"","context":{"request_id":"fc61d990-5aaa-11ef-9041-8ad61b804eb5","message":{"error":"bad value","call":"deparse(call, nlines = 1L)","traceback":["FUN(request, response)","start_bot_process(bot_id)",["parallel$mcparallel({","    tryCatch({","        bot <- TradeBot$new(bot_id, bot_file)","        bot$start()","        while (bot$is_running) {","            later$run_now(all = TRUE, loop = later$global_loop())","            Sys.sleep(0.1)","        }","    }, error = function(e) {","        cat(\"Error in bot process:\", e$message, \"\\n\")","    }, finally = {","        cat(sprintf(\"Bot %s process exiting\\n\", bot_id))","    })","})"],"mcexit(1L, structure(\"fatal error in wrapper code\", class = \"try-error\"))","try(sendMaster(send, FALSE), silent = TRUE)",["tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {","    call <- conditionCall(e)","    if (!is.null(call)) {","        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch))) ","            call <- sys.call(-4L)","        dcall <- deparse(call, nlines = 1L)","        prefix <- paste(\"Error in\", dcall, \": \")","        LONG <- 75L","        sm <- strsplit(conditionMessage(e), \"\\n\")[[1L]]","        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = \"w\") + nchar(sm[1L], type = \"w\")","        if (is.na(w)) ","            w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = \"b\") + nchar(sm[1L], ","                type = \"b\")","        if (w > LONG) ","            prefix <- paste0(prefix, \"\\n  \")","    }","    else prefix <- \"Error : \"","    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), \"\\n\")","    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))","    if (!silent && isTRUE(getOption(\"show.error.messages\"))) {","        cat(msg, file = outFile)","        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())","    }","    invisible(structure(msg, class = \"try-error\", condition = e))","})"],"tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)","tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])","value[[3L]](cond)","deparse(call, nlines = 1L)"]}}}
^CCaught break signal, shutting down Rserve.
[1] TRUE

(base) work@Derecks-MacBook-Air dev % curl "localhost:8080/start-bot"
Bot 1a861785-533f-4cf1-b668-6986da137c23 started%    
(base) work@Derecks-MacBook-Air dev % curl "localhost:8080/stop-bot?id=1a861785-533f-4cf1-b668-6986da137c23"
Bot 1a861785-533f-4cf1-b668-6986da137c23 stopped%

These errors occur seemingly after starting and stopping bots every time.
Question

What could be causing these segmentation faults and memory errors?
How can I properly manage my parallel processes to prevent these crashes?
Is there a better way to implement this bot management system using RestRserve and parallel processing in R?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
NB: related discussion: https://github.com/rexyai/RestRserve/discussions/216#discussioncomment-10331021
